# How to find footprints for Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, footprint

I wanted to have a footprint for capacitor having mouser no: 710-860020475016 and package: AL10x10.5 . Please tell me how i can find that specific part and foot print for Altium designer. I have looked into all Altium libraries but didn't find that component. [image: Image attached]

Comment: Go to data sheet and see its recommended footprint. And then make it. Its too simple.

Comment: As MITU RAJ said, make one. I recommend doing that for ALL footprints you use. Don't use third-party footprints because then you'll get multiple styles and your design just gets ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Wurth have AD libs available for most of their stuff, but really for something like that you should probably just create it.

Creating footprints is a big part of the job, it is worth learning to do it.

http://katalog.we-online.de/en/pbs/WCAP-ATG5/860020475016 bottom of the page, there are download links for cad libraries if you really are that lazy, but you usually need to tweak them to conform to your house standards.

Comment: Making them following the data sheet gives you confidence they're correct. It seems like a big job, and is to begin with, but over time your library will grow, until it's a rarity you have to create new ones.

Comment: When you start out, it can be like 80% of the work in a small project!